# migration Magento 2 to localhost with xampp Admin stuck to login box without fields

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.0.4, windows, xampp

i have a magento 2.0.4 website working on a server. As I want to upgrade it to 2.1.0, I did a backup and installed it on my local server W10 with xampp & composer, localhost (127.0.0.1).

I did clean the cache and removed everything, except .htaccess file from `pub/static` folder, run the command on Magento root :

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

I opened up app/etc/di.xml find the path `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` and replaced to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

the website frontend is good but not the admin backend, it shows just white box in admin and no fields to login in to admin as well. There's no error in the console dev.

I checked as well, my account is not locked.

I did try to install a new fresh magento2 version with xampp and it's working... But not my website version.

Do you have any idea how to make the admin work again?

Comment: Try to remove all content in `var/cache`, `var/page_cache`, `var/generation`, `pub/static` folders. After that run admin url in private browser and check it.

Comment: Did you figured out something?

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned steps it should resolve your problem.

Remove all content in from below mentioned folders:

```
var/cache
var/page_cache
var/generation
pub/static
```

After that run admin url from private browser. Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I followed your steps but it still the same

Comment: Ok after making this change try `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` from command line.

Comment: It doesn't change, I still have login box without fields

Comment: After upgrade have you run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: I didn't do the upgrade yet, I want to transfer it on my local server (xampp) to do the upgrade after but I'm stuck with the admin login without fields